# Latest Versions of libfreenect

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, kinect, libraries, openkinect

I have written some software for a computer vision project, and want to make sure it is using the latest version of the libfreenect libraries and headers. Unfortunately, I can't figure out which are more up to date. There are several packages included with ROS, but there is also the libfreenect-dev package, which is what I used initially and referenced [here](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started). There have also been other random versions that can be found under the keyword "freenect".

My team is using the ROS package for other things, so I will probably use that except that the ROS package is a pain to work with and it doesn't, by default, offer support for the Kinect Accelerometer. I want to know where I can find the latest versions for Ubuntu libfreenect so I can make a better decision on what to use.

Comment: compile the file like "g++ -M test.cpp"  . It will list the files included.